# Webcam not working - blank screen

Tags: usb, webcam

My microdia integrated_webcam_hd in my dell laptop is not working. I had reinstalled ubuntu 20.04 in my laptop and then the webcam stopped working. The camera used to work just fine before on the same OS. The webcam is being detected but just shows a blank screen. Any solutions?